# Xvfb doesn't start

Tags: linux, centos, xvfb

I'm trying to start xvfb on CentOS6.
But soon after I type a command to start xvfb, I faced following error.

```
(EE) AIGLX error: swrast exports no DRI extension
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
```

The command I typed is here:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1280x1280x24 &
```

Does anyone know the cause of this error?

Answer (score 4):

as root run

> yum install mesa-dri-drivers